# How do I make the taskbar icon go away?

Tags: c#, taskbar

I want to get rid of the icon in the task bar from my program. [This](http://puu.sh/2WUWE.png) thing. Sorry for not being able to post as an image, but I have to have at least 10 rep to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In winforms use [ShowInTaskbar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.showintaskbar%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

```
ShowInTaskbar = false;
```